# what's the risk: Changing www-data $home

Tags: permissions, apache2, java

Ubuntu 16.04, Apache2

App that I am using employs Java to run, and uses some kind of a license file.  When you run the app, it writes and then reads from a file in the user's home dir.  So I am trying to run the app as part of a cgi script, therefore it runs under www-data account, which by default has no home dir ($home is blank for user www-data).  So the app tries to write to /var/www for which www-data has no write rights, causing the app to crash.  Its a big deal to get the app changed.  App runs fine under ordinary user account, leaving behind a [gibberish].dat file in $home  App is Denkovi v2.6

So what is the risk of me creating /home/www-data and setting it as the home dir for www-data via usermod?  Am I exposing my system to a major risk through the web interface by doing so?

If there is a simpler/better way to do this, please educate me!

Comment: `www-data`'s home directory is `/var/www` (see `getent passwd www-data`).

Comment: Hmmm...if I run "echo $home" as www-data, it returns a blank.  Following returns a blank line:  sudo -H -u www-data bash -c 'echo $home'

Comment: `$HOME`, not `$home`

Comment: Well, OK, so I win the morning's Stupid Prize.  Sorry, thanks for gently smacking me.  But apparently www-data still has no write privs to that folder (mode is 755), which causes the app to fail.  If I change it to 766, would that be safe?

Comment: does this app need to write other things as well? Is the only modification it does in `/var/www` the creation of that file? Does it modify that file after creation?

Comment: The Denkovi app writes to some specific USB folders....but I think I have that resolved.  I don't think it mods the file after creation - based on the file timestamp, it seems to create it the first time the app is run, then just reread it every time the app is run.  I think I see where you are leading me.....give it rights, run the app, create the file, take the rights away?